# Subtract two daily rasters based on name using ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I'm not creative today it seems and I haven't found a way to do the following: I have two folders each containing 10,000+ raster files for daily values with names like 19810101_A and 19810101_B for the first day of January 1981 and so on. Now I want to substract the A-raster files in one folder from the B-ones in the other folder on a day-by-day basis and write them to a third folder.

How can I do this in ModelBuilder?

Comment: Yes it can, you need to research about using a raster iterator and parse path tool to automate this. As a side note 10,000+ rasters will take a long time.

Comment: Maybe try to use a python, that allow you more control then the model builder. For example by using a sorted list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I have no knowledge of python :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After input from radouxju, Martin and Hornbydd and some trial and error I found the Python code below to be working. Problem was mainly the `os.path.split(image)[-1][:-5]` which was replaced with `os.path.basename(image).rstrip(os.path.splitext(image)[1])`

```
import arcpy, glob, os
from arcpy import sa #spatial analyst

liste_a = glob.glob("d:\\folderA\\*.tif") #get a list of tif (or other extension)

for image in liste_a: #loop on images
    print image # just checking...
    image_a = arcpy.sa.Raster(image) #create raster object based on the raster name
    image_b = arcpy.sa.Raster("d:\\folderB\\" + os.path.basename(image).rstrip(os.path.splitext(image)[1]) + ".tif") #idem, but adjust the name
    image_c = image_a - image_b #self explicit
    image_c.save( "d:\\folderC\\" + os.path.basename(image).rstrip(os.path.splitext(image)[1]) + ".tif") #save with new name
```

Thanks for all your help. Definitely need to look into Python more for future work.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import arcpy, glob, os
from arcpy import sa #spatial analyst

liste_a = glob.glob("D:\\folderA\\*.tif") #get a list of tif (or other extension)

for image in liste_a: #loop on images
    print image # just checking...
    image_a = Raster(image) #create raster object based on the raster name
    image_b = Raster("D:\\folderB\\" + os.path.split(image)[-1][:-5] + "B.tif") #idem, but adjust the name
    image_c = image_a - image_b #self explicit
    image_c.save( "D:\\folderC\\" + os.path.split(image)[-1][:-5] + "C.tif") #save with new name
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I always get the error: Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
NameError: name 'Raster' is not defined

Comment: @ChristianH You have to edit the script and add your file names and paths.

Comment: I did of course exchange the path names.

Comment: @ChristianH Try changing `Raster` to `arcpy.sa.Raster` instead then (although it should not be necessary since you import it on the second row).

Comment: Changed the code after some trial and error (see above, after peer review visible). Now it gets til line 9 where it says: Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects

Comment: @ChristianH If line 9 is `image_c =...`, it is probably the typo there causing problems. Should be `image_b` (with underscore) instead of `image-b`. If line 9 is another line, there's more to fix..

Comment: I corrected that typo in my code (you probably can't see it yet, since it's not reviewed), it's still not working and giving me the error mentioned above. To me it seems, it has something to do with the construction of the raster name, where the code tries to add a string to a path to a string.